# Problems with a simple loop

Tags: python, list

I want to make a loop, that sums up the first two items of a list, and stores the result in a new list. After that it should take the first three items of the first list and sum up these and store the result in the same list aswell.

What I try to do:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = []

for i in x:
     s = i + (i+1)
     y.append(s)
```

This does not work at all. Because of my bad understanding its hard to get help from google. I hope some might understand my problem.

Comment: `y = [sum(x[:i]) for i in (2, 3)]` or `y = [sum(x[:2]), sum(x[:3])]`

Comment: In your loop, `i` is not an index, it's the value from the list.

Comment: When you are doing i +(i +1) it's not sums the first tow elements you can do it with enumerat of the list and by the index get the second element

Comment: First of all thanks to your fast responses.
@StevenRumbalski I tried both of your versions. Can i somehow change the code that i do not have to tipe in every Index of the List? I need this for Lists that are much bigger than the text version.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = []

for i in range(2,len(x)+1):
    y.append(sum(x[:i]))
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### **Looks like you want a list comprehension that sums incrementally larger and larger lists as you iterate through**

---

**This will work.**

```py
>>> x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> x
[1,2,3,4]

# Note we put the condition `if i != 0` so that we ignore the first entry in the list
#
# This comprehension essentially is taking the indices for the given list
# and utilizing the indices to generate a subset list of indices (`range(i+1)`)
# and by using these subset indices we can generate a subset of values which
# we can then sum as you requested.
>>> y = [sum([x[idx] for idx in range(i+1)]) for i in range(len(x)) if i !=0]
>>> y
[3, 6, 10]
```

**Let me know if you have any questions!**

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a loop but if you want:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
new_list = []

for count in range(len(x) - 2):
  if count <2:
    new_list.append( sum(x[:count+2]) )

print(new_list)

# OR without loop 

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
new_list = []

sums_of_the_first_two = sum(x[:2])
new_list.append(sums_of_the_first_two)
sums_of_the_first_three = sum(x[:3])
new_list.append(sums_of_the_first_three)

print(new_list)
```

Edit: The 2nd part in the comment of  Steven Rumbalski is the best solution i think